# Why isn't this JavaScript mousemove function working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I'm trying to make this function work so that whatever div it's applied to, the pageSee class will follow with a hyperlink..

This is what I wrote up.. https://jsfiddle.net/LoorLge5/5/

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    body {padding: 500px; background: #ddd; }
    .pageSee { position: absolute; float: left; }
</style>
</head>

<body id="as">

<div id="this">this is awesome</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function ()
    {   
        $('#as').divFollow({
            target: 'http://www.facebook.com/'
        });
    });

    function divFollow(settings)
    {
        return this.each(function ()
        {       
            this.append('<a class="pageSee" src="' + settings.target + '"></a>');

            this.on('mousemove', function(e)
            {
                $('.pageSee').css({
                    left: e.pageX - 5,
                    top: e.pageY - 5
                });
            });
        });
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of issues there:

1. Declaring a global `divFollow` function does nothing to make it a property of jQuery objects. To do that, you add it to `$.fn`:

   ```
   $.fn.divFollow = function() { /* ... */ };
   ```
2. Within the callback of your `each` within the function, `this` will not be a jQuery object, it'll be a raw DOM element. So you'll need to wrap it in a jQuery object: `$(this)` (You're quite correct that in `divFollow`, `this` is a jQuery object.)
3. Inside your `mousemove` handler, you're locating **all** `.pageSee` elements and changing their CSS. You probably just want to do the one related to this specific element.

So at a minimum:

```
// Put it on `$.fn`
$.fn.divFollow = function(settings) {
    return this.each(function() {
        // Wrap `this`
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.append('<a class="pageSee" src="' + settings.target + '"></a>');
        $this.on('mousemove', function(e) {
             // Find the .pageSee within this element only
             $this.find('.pageSee').css({
                 left: e.pageX - 5,
                 top: e.pageY - 5
             });
        });
    });
};

$(function() {
    $('#as').divFollow({
        target: 'http://www.facebook.com/'
    });
});
```

There may be other issues, but hopefully that gets you going.

Comment: That was perfect, I also needed to include the option settings for it to work. settings = $.extend({ target: null }, settings);